# How to get geolocation in html form and post it into php/sql database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am setting up a website similar to AirBnB, when a user is adding an apartment, I need them to be able to click a button to get their longitude and latitude, I then need the longitude and latitude posted into my database via php/sql code.

I have tried a lot of code, such as below, and it works perfectly to get the users current location of the user, which I am happy with, but I am not sure how to post the varibales to php/sql database. I have my database connection working fine.

```
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The geolocation property is not supported in 
IE8 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
```

}

Basically, I need to find out how to post the longitude and latitude from javascript like in the code above to a php file (I know how to post it to the database once it is successfully made accessible in the php file)

Edit: Resolved, this is the code I used in the end:

```
 <input id="lat" type="text" value=""> 
 <input id="long" type="text" value=""> 
 <button onclick="getLocation();">GO</button>
 <script>
    function getLocation()
      {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
        {
         var coordinates = position.coords;
         document.getElementById('lat').value = coordinates.latitude;
         document.getElementById('long').value = coordinates.longitude;
       });
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: make an `ajax` request in the `showPosition` callback function and use the ajax callback to display a marker on the map or whatever is appropriate

Comment: I think you need to do a little research on AJAX

Comment: I have been researching for a long time, tried a lot of things in AJAX but cant seem to figure it out, is there any lead you can give me so I can figure out where to look?

Comment: If you want a working example of an Ajax request with the php: https://codepen.io/iosepa/pen/XoxMRG has a form with the needed php in the comments below the js. Add the form, javascript and php to your server to see how they all work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick and easy ajax function ( not tested ) that gets called by the `Geolocation` callback and sends whatever information is required in the `params` object payload.

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
    }

    /* utility to build querystring from Object */
    function buildparams(p){
        if( p && typeof( p )==='object' ){
            p=Object.keys( p ).map(function( k ){
                return typeof( p[ k ] )=='object' ? buildparams( p[ k ] ) : [ encodeURIComponent( k ), encodeURIComponent( p[ k ] ) ].join('=')
            }).join('&');
        }
        return p;
    };

    /* ultra basic ajax function that only sends a POST request to nominated URL */
    function ajax(url,params,callback){
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )callback( this.response );
        }
        xhr.open('POST',url,true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.send( buildparams( params ) );
    }








    function showPosition( position ) {
        /*
            the callback to the Geolocation request 
            fires the ajax request to whatever backend
            PHP script will process the POST request

            In the PHP script uyou should have access
            to $_POST['lat'] and $_POST['lng']
        */
        var url=location.href;
        var params={ lat:position.coords.latitude,lng:position.coords.longitude };
        var callback=function(r){
            console.info( r );
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        }

        /* trigger the ajax request */
        ajax( url, params, callback );
    }
</script>
```

In the PHP script ( assigned by `url` variable )

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( isset( $_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng'] ) ){
            $lat=$_POST['lat'];
            $lng=$_POST['lng'];

            $sql='insert into `table` (`lat`,`lng`) values (?,?)';
            /* etc */
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: RamRaider the code runs perfectly, but I am unsure which part is the php variable, can you clarify this?

Comment: In the PHP script, identified in the ajax function as `url`, you should have access to the POST array. In that POST array you should find `$_POST['lat']` and `$_POST['lng']` - these correspond to the property names assigned in the javascript `params` object.

Comment: RamRaider I see, i added this to my code, and it runs the html file but not the php file, on the php file i have just echod out the variables to test, but the php file is not running, why is this?

Comment: The updated code does not, in itself, fulfil the desired goal or sending the lat/lng details to a backend script. Presumably you then rely upon the user submitting ( or via js ) a form with the action set to the php script that handles the database insert?? I provided a reasonable solution that would not require further user interaction nor a page reload but you went a different route... Incidentally the PHP code I put in the answer above was NOT intended to be the actual code - it, in itself, does nothing anyway - there is NO output

Comment: My code is inside a form for a user to submit, so it works, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick. Simply build a form object and add the geolocation to it, then send it through an ajax request.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("lat", x.lat);
formData.append("lon", x,lon);    

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: formData.serialize(),
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

---

```
<?php
$lat=$_POST["lat"];
$lon=$_POST["lon"];
```